# Infragistics datagrid when edit text hide

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, infragistics

I am using infragistics wpf controls and trying use datagrid.

The appearance from datagrid looks fine, but when I am going to edit the field, the text disappear half. Consider the pics.

**No Editing**
[image: No Editing]

**When Editing**

[image: When Editing]

As you can see, when I try to edit field, the textbox disappear half.

XAML codesnippet

```
 <igDp:XamDataGrid Theme="Metro" DataSource="{Binding Logins}" IsGroupByAreaExpanded="False"
                                      GroupByAreaLocation="None">
                        <igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                            <igDp:FieldLayoutSettings AddNewRecordLocation="OnBottom" AllowAddNew="True" AllowDelete="True"/>
                        </igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                        <igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                            <igDp:FieldSettings AllowResize="False" LabelWidth="200" LabelTextAlignment="Center" Height="Auto"/>
                        </igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                    </igDp:XamDataGrid>
```

What do I have to do, when editing, that the text won't be disappear?

Comment: Are you using the EditableCellTemplate for any of the columns?

Comment: What is EditableCellTemplate? But I think not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the specific behavior that you see and would recommend doing some testing on your own to gather more information.  The first test I would recommend is to remove the Theme setting and if that resolves the issue then it is related to the theme being applied and you should test with the latest version from Infragistics.  If that still reproduces the issue with the theme applied then you should let them know so they can address the issue.  You can submit a support case/bug to Infragistics here:

https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/submit-support-request